# Deploy Google Cloud Function when source code contains multiple levels/directories

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to [deploy a Google Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/), written in Go, with a code structure containing a subdirectory, like this :

```
function
├── module1
│   ├── go.mod
│   └── module1.go
├── go.mod
└── entrypoint.go
```

But when I deploy the function, using the GCP console or `gcloud` command :

```
# from function/ directory
gcloud functions deploy myfunction --runtime go111 [...]
```

Only `go.mod` and `entrypoint.go` are uploaded (I checked on the *Source* tab of *Function details* in the GCP Console). Thus the function fails to deploy, because obviously `entrypoint.go` use methods from `module1/module1.go`.

The same happens if the source is a `.zip` (containing multiple directories) on Google Cloud Storage :

```
gcloud functions deploy myfunction \
    --runtime go111 \
    --source gs://${BUCKET}/function.zip [...]
```

Is it possible to deploy functions using a code structure with subdirectories? I don't know if the same happens for other runtimes (Python, NodeJS), or if the problem is specific to Go.

#### Edit

I tried to follow this guide : https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/#functions-writing-file-structuring-go (2nd point : *A package at the root of your project that imports code from a sub-package and exports one or more functions*), as suggested in the comments, but without success. Here's the structure I used (works in local) :

```
.
├── function.go
├── go.mod
└── shared
    ├── go.mod
    └── shared.go
```

go.mod

```
module testcloudfunction

require testcloudfunction/shared v0.0.0

replace testcloudfunction/shared => ./shared
```

function.go

```
package function

import (
    "fmt"

    "testcloudfunction/shared"
)

func HelloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, shared.Hello())
}
```

shared/go.mod

```
module testcloudfunction/shared
```

shared/shared.go

```
package shared

func Hello() string {
    return "Hello World!"
}
```

Comment: See here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/#functions-writing-file-structuring-go

Comment: @DazWilkin I tried to follow the guide, but without success. I updated my question with additional info.

Comment: I'll try this out today (am PST). If I can't resolve it, I'll ask Engineering. Kudos for the clearly-explained question and repro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. It works for me with some changes.

I'm *using* `GOPATH` and so am prefixing with `GO111MODULE=on`. If you are outside of `GOPATH`, I think you can just drop the `GO111MODULE=on` environment setting.

Starting with directories and `.go` files only (no `.mod` files).

My path is `github.com/DazWilkin/cloudfuncs`.

IIUC you will need to -- minimally -- prefix module paths with `example.com`.

```golang
package function

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/DazWilkin/cloudfuncs/shared"
)

func HelloFreddie(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, shared.Hello())
}
```

Then, from within my `cloudfuncs` directory:

```sh
GO111MODULE=on go mod init github.com/DazWilkin/test
```

Results in a `go.mod`:

```
module github.com/DazWilkin/cloudfuncs

go 1.11
```

There is *no* `go.mod` file in `.../cloudfuncs/shared`.

Then I deploy using:

```sh
gcloud functions deploy HelloFreddie \
--region=us-central1 \
--entry-point=HelloFreddie \
--runtime=go111 \
--source=$PWD/cloudfuncs \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--trigger-http
```

You can see the result here:
https://us-central1-dazwilkin-190225-54842789.cloudfunctions.net/HelloFreddie

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reproduce the issue and solve it :) FI, I've noticed that in the *Cloud Function* > *Function Details* > *source* tab of the GCP Console, files from the subfolder (`shared`) are not shown. But anyway, this is just a detail, as we can get the full source code by downloading the zip.

Comment: You're welcome! A good feature request. While the console may not permit browsing, it should acknowledge the additional files